# How do I tell if one path is an ancestor of another?

Tags: ruby, filesystems

I need to check if the directory denoted by path string `a` is an ancestor of (or is) the directory or file denoted by path string `b`, and that both paths actually exist

My naive implementation looked like:

```rb
b.starts_with?(a) && File.exist?(b)
```

Examples this fails with:

```rb
# should be false
a = '/foo/bar'
b = '/foo/bartholomew/monkey'

# should be true
a = '/foo/bar'
b = '/foo/../foo/bar/monkey
```

I could make this work by iterating through the parents of file `b` and checking if any matches `a`, but are there any methods in the common libs to make it simpler, like this solution in Python? – [How can I tell if a file is a descendant of a given directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328012/how-can-i-tell-if-a-file-is-a-descendant-of-a-given-directory)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of operating on the strings, let's get a list the directories and check if one starts with the other

```
def is_descendant?(a, b)
  a_list = File.expand_path(a).split('/')
  b_list = File.expand_path(b).split('/')

  b_list[0..a_list.size-1] == a_list
end

is_descendant?('/foo/bar', '/foo/bartholomew/monkey') #=> false
is_descendant?('/foo/bar', '/foo/../foo/bar/monkey') #=> true
```

[`File.expand`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/File.html#method-c-expand_path) seems to be Ruby's equivalent of Python's `os.path.realpath`.

Comment: +1.  This works where my attempt at using [Pathname](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-relative_path_from) fails (e.g. `".." == (a_pathname.relative_path_from b_pathname).to_s[0..1]`)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for your test cases:

```
def descendant?(a, b)
  [a, b].each { |x| x.replace File.expand_path(x) }
  !b.split('/').zip(a.split('/')).any? { |x, y| y != nil && x != y }
end

descendant? '/foo/bar', '/foo/bartholomew/monkey' # => false
descendant? '/foo/bar', '/foo/../foo/bar/monkey'  # => true
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this such that the function checks if either string is an ancestor of the other. Upon re-reading your question, this may not have been what you intended, but oh well...

```
def path_components(path_string)
  File.expand_path(path_string).split('/')
end

# Check if either x_str or y_str is an ancestor of the other.
def is_one_ancestor?(x_str, y_str)
  x_parts = path_components(x_str)
  y_parts = path_components(y_str)

  shorter_length = [x_parts, y_parts].map(&:length).min

  # Find the length of the common prefix of the two paths.
  common_path_length = x_parts.zip(y_parts).take_while do |x,y|
    x == y
  end.length

  # one is an ancestor of the other if the common path length
  # is equal to the length of the shorter path
  common_path_length == shorter_length
end

a = '/foo/bar'
b = '/foo/bartholomew/monkey'
puts is_one_ancestor?(a,b) # false
puts is_one_ancestor?(b,a) # false

c = '/foo/bar'
d = '/foo/../foo/bar/monkey'
puts is_one_ancestor?(c,d) # true
puts is_one_ancestor?(d,c) # true
```